# Using Socket.IO, could I send messages and store them in the database?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot

I want to do a chat in realtime using angular as frontend, springboot as backend and mysql as database. For example, using the Socket.IO library, would I be able to send the messages in realtime to the backend and store in the database?

Comment: Besides what you said above, `message queue` is needed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use the Socket.IO is a JavaScript library for real-time web applications. and bi-directional communication between web clients and server, in your case you use it inside your frontend application with angular.

Comment: Could I store the messages in the database as well?

Comment: Yes absolutely if you're using MySQL as database then you could use the require('MySQL')  and you have the ability to connect your database and handle your script as you wish.

Comment: kindly you find an example of how to connect the socket.io with MySQL [link](https://markshust.com/2013/11/07/creating-nodejs-server-client-socket-io-mysql/), I've recommended you this library because it will make your life easier.r

Comment: I have skills in java, could I use the socket.io with spring boot from backend and angular frontend?

Comment: yes, you could, please try to visit the link above.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking, it looks like it will work.

Comment: because I've experienced angular for frontend and socket.io for real-time discussion also the database in MySQL and it worked for me perfectly

Comment: I wanted to know. Have you just used angular, mysql and socket.io? Or did you also use a backend?

Comment: Well, if you're using angular 6 have a look on this tutorial is the tough part [link](https://alligator.io/angular/socket-io/) and you have to know socket.io it will be another server so inside this server you could call your database and stock your data, is fair enough for you?